# Google cloud identity api to get company owned devices list

Tags: python, go, google-api, google-cloud-identity

I am trying to get a company owned devices  via https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/reference/rest/v1/devices/list using golang.
I have tried using a service account and doing domain wide delegation and even adding scopes .
It seems that the below code always giving empty values(no devices list).

Sample golang code that I used:

```
cloudidentityService, err := cloudidentity.NewService(context.Background(), option.WithCredentialsFile("test.json"),
    option.WithScopes("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-identity.devices.lookup",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-identity.groups","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-identity.groups.readonly",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"))

addevices, err := cloudidentityService.Devices.List().Do()

if len(addevices.Devices) == 0 {
    fmt.Println("empty")
} else {
    for _, u := range addevices.Devices {
        fmt.Println(u.Name)
    }
    return
```

Pls advise.
Stuck badly
Ref code I used is https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client/blob/master/cloudidentity/v1beta1/cloudidentity-gen.go
If anyone can advise via postman that would be great too.

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: I am not getting android device list using the above code  api.

Comment: I see, I missed the part where you mentioned that you are getting an empty list, I thought this code was producing errors.

Comment: @jabbson can you please advise how to get list of devices.I might be  missing something